# Help Installing Linux on Chromebook C720

Tags: linux, system-installation, chrome-book

I've exhausted everything to try to install linux on my Chromebook.
 I've installed ChrUbuntu and crouton successfully but crouton doesn't offer a way to repartition the drive for the installation so I was left with an insufficient amount of memory for my needs in that partition.

ChrUbuntu was too slow and I prefer crouton's ability to switch conveniently between Chrome OS and Ubuntu and I how fast it was. So I tried USB booting GParted but it didn't work. 
I've obviously set the computer to developer mode and set the crossystem dev_boot_usb=1 and changed the firmware to developer but it still won't work. I've tried 3 different kinds of image writing softwares for GParted (tuxboot, netboot, lili usb creator, all listed on GParted site) but they didn't work.

I tried x86 and amd64 images but they didn't work. I've tried both USB slots on the computer but neither of them work. When I try to press ctrl+U on the "Scary screen", it just makes a single beep.

I've also tried booting in legacy and selecting to boot from USB from there but ti says missing operating system, no bootable device. I'm getting very frustrated and I don't know what to do from here.

I've also tried two different USB sticks, and a plain ubuntu distro (no GParted) and a chrome OS but all I get is that single beep. Any help would be fantastic. Acer C720

Answer (score 4):

I posted complete instructions to unbrick an Acer C720 using John Lewis' coreboot and then install Debian.  As a new contributor to StackExchange I can only post two links, so look here on Google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linuxusersgroup/-D9w9_m64zc for the complete post including links and pictures..  I used find/replace to remove all instances of "http" but the rest of the links are intact.

**Unbrick an Acer C720 and install Debian Wheezy**

I bricked my Acer C720-2420 playing with bios updates. Opps.  Here’s how I unbricked it.  I used John Lewis’ excellent website (thanks John, you are the man!) as a general outline.  These instructions outline the concept: ://johnlewis.ie/unbricking-a-samsung-series-5-550-chromebook/

FYI only, info on the bios chip
://www.nexflash.com/NR/rdonlyres/591A37FF-007C-4E99-956C-F7EE4A6D9A8F/0/W25Q64BV.pdf
Buy this equipment:

Bus Pirate v3.3: ://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate from this site:
://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/bus-pirate-v3-assembled-p-609.html?cPath=61_68

CPT-063 Test Clip SOIC8 Pomona 5250
://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00HHH65T4/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o09_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Female to Female Solderless Flexible Breadboard Jumper Cable Wire
://www.amazon.com/Female-Solderless-Flexible-Breadboard-Jumper/dp/B00D7SCMZ8/ref=pd_sim_e_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=126G793PR1R05W7T74DD

**Un-brick**

DISCONNECT THE CHROMEBOOK BATTERY and the AC POWER SUPPLY!

Connect the female ends of the jumper cables to the Bus Pirate (BP) and the SOIC8 clip such that the SOIC8 connects to the bios chip ports (ports?) as shown in the text below.  I used the Bus Pirate (BP) pin-out on this website:
://dangerousprototypes.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=5187&view=unread#p50375
I reviewed the manual for both the W25Q64FV and the W25Q32B to confirm that both chips have the same pin-out.

```
On BP .......... On SOIC Clip => W25Q32B chip
CS     <=======> CS (1)
GND    <=======> GND (4)
CLK    <=======> CLK  (6)
3V3    <=======> VCC (8)
MOSI   <=======> DI (IO0)
MISO   <=======> DO (IO1)
```

Keep in mind that 2 of the wires connected to the bios chip won’t be used and 4 of the pins on the BP won’t be used.  Triple-check the pinouts or you may permanently fry the chip.  When you are done it should look like this:

[image]
[image]

To run the Bus Pirate (BP) I used a MacBook Air with Debian 3.6 installed on Parallels.  I used Debian only in command line mode (no GUI) and followed the instructions below to set up the BP on the Mac: ://hardcoreforensics.com/research-hardware/tool-setup/buspirate-v3/
I did not use ZTerm but I did use the instructions to install FTDI drivers for my Mac, after which I connected to the BP using ‘screen’ as discussed below.

Update BP firmware using instructions posted here (I did not upgrade until after I fixed my Chromebook but I hear it goes much faster if you do upgrade):
://wiki.yobi.be/wiki/Bus_Pirate#7816-3_T.3D0_at_arbitrary_baudrate

If you haven’t yet, connect the USB cable from the Mac to the BP.
If Parallels asks, choose to connect the new device to your Linux virtual machine (VM).
In Linux either open a Terminal (black screen with DOS-looking console interface) or otherwise get to a bash prompt.  Assuming you logged in as ‘root’ simply type the commands below.  If you aren’t root then preface each set of commands with sudo.

If Linux says you aren’t in the sudoers list then follow this guide to fix the problem (FYI, I always use the program nano to edit /etc/sudoers/ and have never had a problem.

```
apt-get install screen
apt-get install flashrom upx
cd /home/<your username>
mkdir core
cd /core
```

Any folder name will do; I used core just for the heck of it.

wget "s://johnlewis.ie/Chromebook-ROMs/coreboot-peppy-seabios-180714.rom"
This is the file for an Acer C720 Chromebook.  If you are flashing any other system, this is not the right file.  You can search on John’s excellent site (s://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-archive/) for other bioses built for other Chromebooks.  There are a ton of bios downloads available on the web.

Find which port your BP is using to connect to your computer:

```
cd /sys/class/tty
ls -la | less
```

look for something with a USB in it, such as ....USB1, etc

connect to BP:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB1 115200 8N1
```

If screen failed to connect and aborted you may have the wrong number next to ‘USB’.  Double check the files in the /sys/class/tty folder….or just try ...ttyUSB0 and see if it works.

hit the i key and you should see:

```
Bus Pirate v3b
Firmware v5.10 (r559)  Bootloader v4.4
DEVID:0x0447 REVID:0x3046 (24FJ64GA002 B8)
://dangerousprototypes.com
```

If so your BP is working.  If not...google for help.
Quit BP with:

```
Ctrl-a \
```

I did not update the BusPirate firmware but folks indicated that it works much faster if you do.

Check that flashrom is install and can communicate with the bios chip:

```
sudo flashrom -p buspirate_spi:dev=/dev/ttyUSB0
```

** You must run the flashrom commands as root or with the sudo construct.

If flashrom is not installed:

```
sudo apt-get install flashrom
```

I ended up with flashrom v0.9.5.2-r1546

Make sure you are in the directory that contains the .rom file you downloaded from John’s site, then:

```
/sys/class/tty# flashrom -V -p buspirate_spi:dev=/dev/ttyUSB1 -w coreboot-peppy-seabios-180714.rom
```

The command assumes that you are using USB1 to connect to the BP and that ‘coreboot-peppy...’ is the right firmware file.

Wait between 30 minutes and 10 hours and it should work.  I started it and went to sleep.  It was done when I woke up the next morning.  Remove the SOIC clip and then hit the power button on the laptop.  It should boot and stop at “Select boot device:” screen (see below).  Now you can install Linux using a USB pen drive installation.

FYI: I found instructions on the web that directed the command “flashrom -VVV -p buspirate_spi:dev=/dev/ttyUSB0 -w bios.bin” but that did not work for me.

**Install Debian Linux**

Download the newest version of Debian (s://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/debian-installer/)
 and create a bootable USB stick using these instructions: ://okomestudio.net/biboroku/?p=1986 
* These instructions assume you are using a working Linux installation (I used Debian on Parallels) but they might work on OSX, I don't know.

I used debian-7.7.0-amd64-netinst but the newest version (as of 1/29/2015 is 7.8.0) would be this file:

```
://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.8.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-7.8.0-amd64-netinst.iso
```

These commands worked for me.  They help you locate the USB stick (/dev/sdb1) and mount it (to the /media directory.  dd copies the installation iso file to the USB stick.  The last command unmounts the USB stick.

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo mkdir /media/USB
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/USB -o uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
sudo dd if=debian-7.7.0-amd64-netinst.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M; sync
umount /media/USB
```

Now insert the USB drive into the Chromebook, startup, press the ESC key to select the boot menu, select the USB drive, run the installer, and hopefully you now have Debian.

FYI, for the install I choose to use the “Guided - use entire” option to install Debian on the entire disk.  In hindsight I should have created a 10 gig partition for the OS so it would be easier to backup.

The screen, trackpad, and kernel will need work.

Fix the screen resolution: Once booted change your screen resolutions:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
then add these entries: 
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Save and close.  Then type `update-grub`

**Fix the trackpad**

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
then add these lines: 
deb ://.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main
deb-src ://.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main
```

Save and close.  Then type `sudo apt-get update` to download a list of possible upgrades

Type:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 -t wheezy-backports
```

Reboot.

Enter the following commands:

```
wget “s://raw.githubusercontent.com/liangcj/AcerC720CrunchBang/master/c720crunchbangtp_v2”
sudo chmod 0755 c720crunchbangtp_v2
sudo ./c720crunchbangtp_v2
```

Reboot. Touchpad should be working.

**Update the kernel**

On your Chromebook go here: s://blog.mdosch.de/ and either 1) click the “kernel”  tag (usually in red) to download the kernel (.deb file) or copy the link and use wget to download it in terminal.  Either way, get the file.
Example file: ://files.mdosch.de/2015-01/linux-image-3.18.4-c720_20150127_amd64.deb
Ex: wget “://files.mdosch.de/2015-01/linux-image-3.18.4-c720_20150127_amd64.deb”

Using the terminal go to the folder containing the file you just downloaded and type this (remember to use the name of the file you just downloaded):
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.18.4-c720_20150127_amd64.deb

Restart your Chromebook.  When it boots up you should be presented with a list of installed kernels.  Choose the newest one.  I won’t claim that what worked for me will definitely work for you, but I hope it does.  Thanks again to the tech geniuses who posted the various fixes that I borrowed.

Answer (score 0):

From google with out opening the case:  http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/acer-c720-chromebook#TOC-Legacy-Boot-Doesn-t-Work

Legacy Boot Doesn't Work

Sometimes it's possible to break the SeaBIOS install in the flash (sometimes doing innocuous things like tweaking the GBB flags). If you do get into such a situation:

Check that dev_boot_legacy is set to 1 when you run crossystem
If it isn't, then see the normal Legacy Boot section above
if it is, then see below

You can safely reset the copy of SeaBIOS in your flash by running (as root):

```
# chromeos-firmwareupdate --sb_extract /tmp
# flashrom -w /tmp/bios.bin -i RW_LEGACY
```

As it is necessary to do this from a shell you may have to reinstall chrome to complete this, instructions are available on the same sight as this info. A hassle, but only cost a usb flash drive, some time, and doesn't void your warranty.

I accidentally broke seabios on my c720 and this fixed it.

It is also worth noting the page posted has all the info you need about booting from usb to install ubuntu